# Can you get X-forwarded-for from Stud > HAProxy > nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, haproxy, stunnel

I'm terminating SSL with Stud and forwarding the request to HAProxy which determines if it's a WebSocket connection and either forwards the request to Node.js or to nginx.  The problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to get the X-forwarded-for from Stud.  When I set write-ip in the stud conf my requests fail.

Is this possible with such a stack?

Comment: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt It appears that haproxy 1.5-dev3 is required to allow the appending of "accept-proxy" to your port binding.  Still reading...thanks in meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stud is a "dumb" proxy, so it can't alter the headers in any way. HAProxy -> Nginx can do what you want certainly.

An option is pound instead of stud.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is hitch: https://github.com/varnish/hitch

Has PROXY support, works with Varnish and haproxy.